# How to download an uploaded stored file from the database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

Im trying to implement a download functionality to an uploaded pdf file in my app. For some reason the record can not be found? If I check the GET Request I see that it tries to use the url ending "/resumes/download.5". 5 is the record id from the stored file. **What am I missing?** How can I debug issues like that in the future? Byebug did not work this time for some reason.

**views/resumes/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Download", resume_download_path(@resume) %>
```

**resumes_controller.rb**

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :catch_not_found
  before_action :find_resume, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :download ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
  end

  def new
    if @resume = current_user.resume
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      @resume = Resume.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @resume = current_user.build_resume(resume_params)
    if @resume.save
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @resume.update resume_params
      redirect_to @resume, notice: "Your resume was successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @resume.destroy
    redirect_to new_resume_path, notice: "Your resume was successfully deleted!"
  end

  def download
    send_data @resume, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "attachment"
  end

  private

  def resume_params
    params.require(:resume).permit( :user_id, :download_file, :remove_download_file)
  end

  def find_resume
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
  end

  def catch_not_found
    yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found')
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root 'welcomes#index'
  resources :resumes

  get "resumes/download", as: "resume_download"

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

**When clicking on the download link:**

```
Started GET "/resumes/download.5" for 77.8.13.5 at 2017-08-23 21:22:14 +0000
Cannot render console from 77.8.13.5! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ResumesController#show as 
  Parameters: {"id"=>"download"}
  Resume Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "resumes".* FROM "resumes" WHERE "resumes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Redirected to https://rails-tutorial-martinbortowski.c9.io/
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/" for 77.8.13.5 at 2017-08-23 21:22:15 +0000
Cannot render console from 77.8.13.5! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by WelcomesController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcomes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 38.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :resumes do
  get :download, on: :member
end
```

Will give you an idiomatically correct REST route:

```
resumes/:id/download
```

Change your link to:

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_resume_path(@resume), "data-turbolinks" => false %>
```

See [Rails Routing from the Outside In - Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Comment: Godlike! It takes me to a website which has only a "#" as content... I need to refresh the url then the download prompt pops up?! Should it not prompt automatically because I have set disposition: "attachment" on the download action?

Comment: `disposition: "attachment"` should open a download prompt. However you're not really sending a PDF.  `send_data @resume, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "attachment"` won't magically turn your model into a PDF. You need to use a PDF builder like prawn or send a user uploaded PDF with `send_file`.

Comment: The record is a user uploaded PDF file ;) I have changed send_data to send_file but when I click on the link I'm getting now this error: "no implicit conversion of Resume into String" any hints?

Comment: You need do `send_file @resume.file_name_or_whatever`.

Comment: The wierd behavior with the page with an `#` might be turbolinks. Try changing the link to `<%= link_to "Download", download_resume_path(@resume), "data-turbolinks" => false %>`

Comment: Perfect it works now! One more question why do I need to specify on a file name on send_file? So I guess send_file should only be used if it is a static file in the public directory? Thanks again! ;)

Comment: Because you can't implicitly send a model instance and expect Rails to know what to do with it.

Comment: But if you are actually storing the file as a blob in the db you can use `send_data(@resume.download_file, type: "application/pdf")`.

Answer (score 0):

You download link seems to be wrong.

change in your **routes.rb**

```
get "resumes/download", as: "resume_download"
```

to

```
controller :resumes do
  get "resumes/download/:id" => :show, as: :resume_download
end
```

**views/resumes/show.html.erb**

change your link

```
<%= link_to "Download", resume_download_path(@resume) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Download", resume_download_path(id: @resume) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Im getting now: "NoMethodError in Resumes#show" - "undefined method `resume_download_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000056736a8>:0x00000005645640>" Do you have any hints how I should tackle this issue?

Comment: Okay no error message now but if I click on download link nothing happens... chrome console says: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http s://rails-tutorial-martinbortowski.c9.io/uploads/resume/download_file/5/pdf-sample.pdf".

Comment: @trickydiddy I can't really access the link as cloud9 redirect me to the login page.

Comment: It is basically show page of the record... nothing changed expect the url there is "dowload" in between: resumes/download/5... I guess the download controller action is wrong...

Comment: what does your `@resume` contains in _download_ action ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152681/discussion-between-roshan-and-trickydiddy).